# Будет ли это жёстким прям нарушением всех правил орфографии, если имя будет «'Лизавета»?

Tags: апостроф

Будет ли это жёстким прям нарушением всех правил орфографии, если имя будет *'Лизавета* — с апострофом то бишь? Так вообще нельзя даже в паспорте имя себе такое поставить? Нельзя это по каким-то правилам оправдать? Может, это, можно сказать, *авторская орфография*? Может, можно сказать, что, так как это имя *Елизавета* без *Е*, надо так писать?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В рамках авторской орфографии вы вольны писать любые имена, даже если они содержат апострофы или начинаются с мягкого знака. Но "оправдать" это в рамках традиционной грамматики русского языка нельзя, так как нет функции, которую бы выполнял апостроф. Обычно он отделяет одну часть слова от другой (различные "д" или латиницу от кириллических наращений).Ещё вы можете апострофом заменить ерик или твёрдый знак. На этом "оправдываемые" функции апострофа в русском заканчиваются.

Да, вы можете использовать его в начале имён, но задайте себе один важный вопрос: "Какую мысль должен уловить читатель из этого знака?". Как читаете это вы — никто знать не знает, а потому это просто будет восприниматься как выпендрёж.

Форма "Лизавета" среди имён встречается, как и "Катерина". Они не требуют апострофов.

P.S. Эксперименты в рамках языка это отлично. Но они должны быть понятны читателю и реализовывать какой-то замысел. Если я пишу, что 0ч'К@р'$cЪ пошёл в 2ал'еt, только ради того, чтобы сказать, что очкарик пошёл в туалет, то это усложнит чтение, но никак не обогатит текст ни художественностью, ни смыслом. Желаю вам именно осмысленных идей, украшающих родную речь, а не наоборот.